# Jenkinsfile - stop pipeline when catch error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am having a problem with my pipeline in Jenkins.

I perform a path search for files with the specified extension. I then execute php -l with the previously found files.
Everything works okay but I would like if php -l finds an error then the build and step go to UNSTABLE state and further execution of the pipeline is stopped.
I managed to do it this way but then build and step are in a FAILED state

```
} catch (Exception e) {
            error("${e}")
```

Part of code my pipeline.

```
def check(){
    stage('Validate files') {
        try {
            sh "find . -type f -iregex '.*\\.\\(php\\)' | xargs -I % sh -c 'php -l \'%\''" 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error("${e}")
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone smarter can direct me to a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an example to work but maybe not exactly what you wanted. I used unstable() to mark the stage / build and then checked for the exit code of the sh step to return or continue the pipeline.

There are 2 if's as you need to return outside of a stage to not just return from the stage.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

try {
    node {
        def exitCode = 0
        exitCode = check()
        if (exitCode != 0){
            return
        }
        somethingelse()
    }
} catch (Throwable err) { // catch all exceptions
        throw err
} finally {}

def check(){
    stage('Validate files') {
            exitCode = sh script:"exit 1", returnStatus:true
            if (exitCode !=0){
                unstable('message')
            }
        }
    return exitCode
}

def somethingelse(){
    stage('Something'){
            echo "somethingelse"
    }
}
```